# BMW 335xi has this burning oil smell wh/is getting worse

Tags: oil

My husband had insisted it is the turbo chargers overflow area?
I'm unfamiliar w/ bmw's but grew up working on engines and cars w/dad and brother.
This smell is simply not right.
Getting chokingly bad.
Also, checked oil. Color sooooo black it looks in need of change. He not changed it in some 3-4 months of hard driving, lots milage.
Now claims catbacks clogged? Don't cause, "burning oil," smell, supposedly , "rotten eggs?"
What do you suggest?
Small oil puddles left every time car stopped. Rub fingers in them. Definitely oil smell, not tranny, or coolant. Black oil stain left on white rag. 
Change the oil?
Are the cats burning?

Comment: If cats were clogged would assume you would have performance issues not just smell. If oil is getting to exhaust you would likely see blue smoke. It seems likely you have an oil leak which perhaps is falling on exhaust/manifold and burning giving u the smell. Try and track down where the leak is from, suspect it may be high up and running down